# Setter method not working for another Object with @DataObject in vertx

Tags: java, asynchronous, proxy, vert.x, setter

I'm new to Vertx and Asynchronous programmjng.I'm using @DataObject annotation in my model. and my model look like

```
@DataObject(generateConverter = true)
class Parent{
   private Child child;
   //some primitives
  
  // getters and setters
  // toJson, fromJson methods from converter
}
```

My problem is, when i try to set value using  method setChild(c),  still child is null in parent but primitives works fine. And class Child is normal model without @DataObject annotation.
Anyone please clarify why setter not working as expected, is it because of annotation or any other thing am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by making child objects also DataObjects. whatever objects annotated with @DataObject is only available through getter, other values which are object type values without @DataObject are null.